# Share a file without saving it on the external storage

Tags: java, android, file, save

I am using the following code to allow the user to share a bitmap,

```
try {

                    File save_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(save_dir
                            + "/test.jpg");

                    final_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("image/jpeg");

                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.parse("file:///" + save_dir + "/test.jpg"));


                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
                            getString(R.string.share_dialog_title)));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Error in sharing.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

the problem is, the if the device has no SD Card, the file will not be saved.

is there is any good way to save it to the internal storage, in somewhere other apps can access, since saving it in the applications data directory will not allow other applications to access it.

Regards

Comment: in your app data directory with [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

Comment: @zapi, I tried
File save_dir = mainActivity.getDir("cache", mainActivity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
but still other apps can't access it

Comment: if you do `(new File(save_dir, "test.jpg")).setReadable(true, false);` before sharing it?

Comment: File has not setReadable, when I paste your last code an error appears in eclipse

Comment: nvm, I fixed it by
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + final_file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: `File#setReadable()` is Java 1.6+ which might not work with Android < Honeycomb - `chmod 777` might be a bit too much if you don't want other apps to be able to modify that file. `chmod 664` should be enough & should be the same as `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.