# Sending from web-service received VCard via email, without saving it on device storage

Tags: java, android, file, save

Here's the situation:
I get two VCards from our web-service and I have to share them via email (or any other suitable channel - not really relevant).
I could save them to files, and then send URIs to the intent using `putParcelableArrayListExtra`, but I'd really like not to use storage, because I'd rather not nag user with storage permissions just because of this.
I did see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213296/share-a-file-without-saving-it-on-the-external-storage), which looks like it does what I need to do (haven't tried it, yet). However, is there any cleaner way of achieving this?
Since there is limited amount of fields on the VCard (about 10), would it be okay to just make `Parcelable` object of my own, copy fields from received VCard and share it as *text/x-vcard* using `putParcelableArrayListExtra`?
I'd like someone to just steer me in the right direction, since I'm quite lost right now.

Comment: FileProvider is the answer ... you can share your app private file(so you don't need storage permissions) with other apps using it ... you may also use ContentProvider directly if you wana provide this information from memory/database directly

Comment: @Selvin, copy your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Selvin said in the comment:

> FileProvider is the answer ... you can share your app private file(so you don't need storage permissions) with other apps using it ... you may also use ContentProvider directly if you wana provide this information from memory/database directly